# Clang-format breaks Objective-C string literals despite high penalty setting

Tags: clang-format

I would like to prevent clang-format from automatically breaking string literals in my Objective-C code.

Inside my .clang-format file, I have set the penalty to a very high number:

```
PenaltyBreakString: 2147483647
```

Calling `clang-format -i folder/**/*.m` still breaks strings:

**old:**

```
#define DISPO_NO_DATA_EASYSCOTT NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"DISPO_NO_DATA_EASYSCOTT", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], @"Bislang hast du noch keine Dispo für diesen Drehtag hochgeladen.\nBitte logge dich dafür online auf my.easyscott.com ein und lade die Dispo im Bereich „Import / Export“ hoch", @"Anzeige in der Dispo, wenn eine Serververbindung besteht, jedoch auf dem Server kein Dokument hinterlegt ist (für easySCOTT). \n erzeugt einen Zeilenumbruch");
```

**new:**

```
#define DISPO_NO_DATA_EASYSCOTT                                                                   \
  NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"DISPO_NO_DATA_EASYSCOTT", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle],       \
                                    @"Bislang hast du noch keine Dispo für diesen Drehtag "      \
                                    @"hochgeladen.\nBitte logge dich dafür online auf "          \
                                    @"my.easyscott.com ein und lade die Dispo im Bereich "        \
                                    @"„Import / Export“ hoch",                                   \
                                    @"Anzeige in der Dispo, wenn eine Serververbindung besteht, " \
                                    @"jedoch auf dem Server kein Dokument hinterlegt ist (für "  \
                                    @"easySCOTT). \n erzeugt einen Zeilenumbruch");
```

**expected:**

```
#define DISPO_NO_DATA_EASYSCOTT    \
  NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"DISPO_NO_DATA_EASYSCOTT", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle],  \
                                    @"Bislang hast du noch keine Dispo für diesen Drehtag hochgeladen.\nBitte logge dich dafür online auf my.easyscott.com ein und lade die Dispo im Bereich „Import / Export“ hoch", \
                                    @"Anzeige in der Dispo, wenn eine Serververbindung besteht, jedoch auf dem Server kein Dokument hinterlegt ist (für easySCOTT). \n erzeugt einen Zeilenumbruch");
```

---

```
clang-format --version                                                                                                                                                                                   
clang-format version 3.7.0 (tags/google/testing/2015-04-02)
```

was installed on a mac through homebrew

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Seems to be a bug in clang format.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try a smaller value… the [documentation mentions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#PenaltyBreakString) the parameter for `PenaltyBreakString` is `unsigned` but it doesn't indicate the size of it.
2. You could mark the line(s) to be ignored and format them as you desire without having to put large arbitrary values into your `.clang-formt` file.

e.g.

```
// clang-format off
...your code...
// clang-format on
```

Comment: I have tried 10000 as the penalty string as well. If you set a larger value it will indeed tell you that your .clang-format file is invalid